# English text google translate drop down

Tags: google-translate

When I embed google translate code into my website. Text in drop down is Vietnamese because my location Vietnam. May be if your location is France, this text drop down is french. I don't want this. I want English even your location anywhere.

[image]

Please help me. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Why do you want the text to be in english? I mean, *who* are you translating *for*? Yourself? Or the people that visit your site? The whole point of the dropdown is to present something *that person* understands.

Comment: Because, I want to custom Flag Icon for [France Flag] [Vietnam Flag]
.....
Code Jquery: 
var frClick = jQuery(frame).contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains('+lang+')').get(0);             jQuery(frClick).click();

So sometime lang = 'Tiếng Pháp' , sometime  lang = 'Franche' because your location . It translate  incorrect

Comment: Hello,
I have removed your duplicated link to image since only an actual image is enough, you don't need to post a separate link again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try lang='en' attribute of select tag.